# Expander collapses after data reset

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

WPF expander collapses after the itemsource/data is refreshed.
How can I open the single node that was previously opened, I'm using MVVM Light

Datagrid > GroupStyle > Setter > Control Template > Expander

Comment: Can you provide some example XAML? Is the `Expander` part of a `DataTemplate`? `ItemSource` on what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a boolean property in your view model and bind `Expander.IsExpanded` to it.